# Unix one-liner to match 2 sections of a file

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a log file that has something like this:

```
blah blah
blah
blah mypattern blah
blah mypattern blah
blah
blah mypattern blah
blah mypattern blah
blah
```

I want a one-liner to read the above from standard input (i.e. in a single pass), print the 2 sets of lines with mypattern, then exit straight after printing the second set of lines.

In cases where i only wanted one set of lines i used the following one-liner:

```
sed '1,/mypattern/d' |sed '/mypattern/!q'
```

as you can see, one line out here or there isn't a big deal.

Edit: this is roughly my expected output

```
blah mypattern blah
blah mypattern blah
blah mypattern blah
blah mypattern blah
```

It isn't a big deal if it adds or misses a line here or there on either side of the boundary. What is important that, for infinite input, it will terminate if there are 2 finite sections of the pattern, with finite gaps in between.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Your code for the one set case doesn't print the first line of the set.

Comment: @Barmar correct. I'm ok with that, as long as it prints the majority of each set - in reality the starting and ending lines of the match aren't important.

Comment: this `sed -n '/mypattern/p' file`

Comment: you don't want a third set to be printed if any ?or the case don't happend, so the line of Avinash Raj suite well the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This counts the number of groups of lines matching `mypattern` and exits after the second groups ends.  Thus, even if the logfile were infinite, this command will terminate.

```
awk '/mypattern/{c+=!f;f=1;print;next} {f=0} c==2{exit}' logfile
```

*Explanation:*

The code has two variables: `f` is a flag and `c` is a counter.

- `/mypattern/{c+=!f;f=1;print;next}`

  `f` is a flag. It is zero when we are outside a group of lines matching `mypattern` and one when we are inside.

  For any line matching `mypattern`, the group counter, `c`, is incremented if this is the first line in the group, that is, if `f==0`.  `f` is then set to one to indicate that we are now in a group.  The line is printed.  The `next` command tells `awk` to skip any remaining commands and start over on the next line.
- `f=0`

  If we get to this statement, that means that we are outside a group and the group flag `f` is therefore set to zero.
- `c==2{exit}`

  If we get to this statement, we are outside of a group and, if `c==2`, we have already seen two complete groups.  Thus, we `exit` awk.

Answer (score 1):

Technically a one-liner but maybe not as terse as you want.  On the plus side, the result is exact.

```bash
awk 'BEGIN { c=0; s=0; } /mypattern/ { if (!s) c++; s=1; print($0); next; } /./ { if (c >= 2) exit; s=0; }'
```

It passes the following test:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -eu

function mkinput {
    for i in $(seq $1)
    do
        hexdump /dev/urandom | head -n $((1 + $RANDOM % 10))
        for j in $(seq $((1 + $RANDOM % 10)))
        do
            echo "blah mypattern blah (i = $i, j = $j)"
        done
    done
    # Produce an infinite stream of input.
    hexdump /dev/urandom
}

mkinput 10 | awk 'BEGIN { c=0; s=0; } /mypattern/ { if (!s) c++; s=1; print($0); next; } /./ { if (c >= 2) exit; s=0; }'
```

Possible output:

```
blah mypattern blah (i = 1, j = 1)
blah mypattern blah (i = 1, j = 2)
blah mypattern blah (i = 1, j = 3)
blah mypattern blah (i = 2, j = 1)
blah mypattern blah (i = 2, j = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/mypattern/{:a;p;n;//ba;x;s/^/x/;/xx/q;x}' file
```

Use the `-n` option for `grep-like` nature. Filter on `mypattern` and use the hold space as a counter as to when to quit processing.

or programatically:

```
sed -n '/mypattern/{:a;p;n;//ba;H;x;s/\n/&/2;x;T;q}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl, rather long-liner, <strike>untested</strike>:

```
perl -ne 'if (m/mypattern/) { $cnt++ unless $in; $in=1; print; } else { $in=0; exit if $cnt == 2; }'
```

Expanded and "proper Perl" version for better understanding:

```perl
my $cnt=0;
my $in=0;
while (<>) {
    if m/mypattern/ {
        $cnt++ unless $in;
        $in = 1;
        print;
    } else {
        $in = 0;
        exit if $cnt == 2;
    }
}
```

**Update:** Tested with

```
aa
aa mypattern aa 1
aa mypattern aa 1
aa mypattern aa 1
aa
aa
aa mypattern aa 2
aa
aa mypattern aa 3
aa mypattern aa 3
aa mypattern aa 3
aa
```

returning

```
aa mypattern aa 1
aa mypattern aa 1
aa mypattern aa 1
aa mypattern aa 2
```